# How to return only 1 row with Oracle Join and Case?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one case. Check Tables below:

```
Table Jeans unique on onwer and Source
--------------------------------
ID  | Source | Prices | Owner
1   | Macy   | 23     | 1
2   | Nike   | 25     | 1
3   | KFC    | 12     | 1

Table Pant unique on onwer and Source
--------------------------------
ID  | Source | Prices | Owner
1   | Macy   | 10     | 1
2   | Nike   | 28     | 1
3   | KFC    | 19     | 1

Table Owner
--------------------------------
ID  | Name   | 
1   | John   |
```

**Note: Jeans and Pant are not necessarily to have 3 sources.**

So we have such tables, Onwer 1:* Pant and Jeans. Here is the logic:

1. Source first then clothes
2. Priority of Source: Macy > Nike > KFC
3. If Jeans and Pant has same source, Jeans > Pant
4. If Jeans only has Nike, but Pant has Macy, take Pant from Macy.

Now basic on above tables, I want to decide where and what John should buy and **how much he should bring**.

```
Select o1.name, 
case when j1.source = 'Macy' then j1.prices #1 if Macy has Jeans, pick Jeans from Macy and end
     when p1.source = 'Macy' then p1.prices #2 if Macy doesn't has Jeans but has Pant, pick Pant from Macy and end
     when j1.source = 'Nike' then j1.prices #3
     when p1.source = 'Nike' then p1.prices #4
     when j1.source = 'KFC' then j1.prices #5
     when p1.source = 'KFC' then p1.prices #6
END AS Money
from Owner o1, Jeans j1, Pant p1
where o1.ID = j1.ID and  p1.ID =  o1.ID;
```

I want the result to be:

```
|Name | Money |
|John | 23    |
because according to the logic, Macy first, then Jeans. If Macy doesn't have Jeans, then it will be Macy Pant 10.
```

Unfortunately, above SQL return all 6 rows. I want the case goes in sequence, the order of case matters, if contition 1 fits, just return 1 and go to next owner.

```
Java
if(jeans.source = "Macy") {
    return jeans.price;
}  else if(pant.source = "Macy") {
    return pant.price;
} else {
    if(jeans.source = "Nike") {
        return jeans.price;
    }  else if(pant.source = "Nike") {
        return pant.price;
    } else {
        if(jeans.source = "KFC") {
            return jeans.price;
        }  else if(pant.source = "KFC") {
            return pant.price;
        }
    }
}
```

I really need help for this, and I have to do such logic in SQL. You don't have to use my case SQL, as long as the SQL gives right output will be good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your table `pants` is suppose to be optional, we will use left join on this.then `coalesce()` function to check first `jeans` before `pants`. a `subquery` to generate your `sortorder` based on item type first.

```
select t1.name, t1.price from (
select t1.name
    , coalesce(t2.price, t3.price) as price
    , case when t2.source='Macy' then 1
        when t2.source='Nike' then  2
        when t2.source='KFC' then 3
        else 100
        end as sortorder
from Owner t1
inner join Jeans t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
left join Pant t3 on t3.ID = t1.ID) t1
where rownum = 1
order by t1.sortorder asc
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give a try at work. I also updated my question. It is not a switch case,  more of if else. Also Jeans and Pant are unique on ownerID and source.